# What is the generator of $\pi_9(S^2)$?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, homotopy-theory

This is more or less the same question as 
[ [What is the generator of $\pi_9(S^3)$?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/76899/what-is-the-generator-of-pi-9s3) ], except what I would like to know is if it is possible to describe this map in a way 
not only topologists can make sense of.

[EDIT] (Following the advice of  Ryan Budney.)   A purely  geometric construction 
like the famous Hopf fibration for $\pi_3(S^2)$  would be perfect. 
(Something like a  map $S^9\to S^2$ or   $S^9\to S^3$  which may be written 
down in equations.)  But I understand that there is little hope for that.

A less explicit but probably more reasonable approach is to try and  represent this homotopy class by a framed 7-manifold in ${\mathbb R}^9$  following Pontryagin. 
In fact, any information about such a manifold may be of help. Is it really complicated?

I  am not really familiar with  the work of Jie Wu, but  what I have read this far makes sense to me. So, the answer can also be along this lines, but if so I would like to see more then hints. (This  computation looks horrendous, and I probably  cannot handle it by myself.)

Comment: You might find some algebraic descriptions in the work of Jie Wu. For example, facts listed on [his home page](http://www.math.nus.edu.sg/~matwujie/Research2.html) imply that $\pi_9(S^2)$ is the center of the group $G(n)$ with generators $x_1$, ..., $x_9$ and relations $x_1\cdots x_9=1$ and moreover all commutators involving every generator trivial. Or also, $\pi_9(S^2)$ is the $9$th homology group of the group of Brunnian braids.

Comment: As far as I know the isomorphism Jie Wu is using is rather indirect, making it difficult to see what precisely the map $S^9 \to S^2$ is.

Comment: It's pretty complicated in terms of Wu's isomorphism as well; for example, there's a number of easy-to-obtain elements corresponding to iteration of nontrivial stable element in $\pi^s_1$, which can be obtained as $\alpha_1 = [x_1, x_2]$ = Hopf map, $\alpha_2 = [[x_1, x_2], [x_1, x_3]] = \pi_4(S^2)$ and so on; as someone may know, fifth iterate $S^7 \to S^2$ becomes trivial, and you have to find less obvious elements in the centre of $G(n)$ to represent generator of $\pi_9$.

Comment: @RyanBudney Well I would say at least the first isomorphism is quite straightforward; the problem is, I believe, in locating a nontrivial element. Essentially it is the Moore normalization of the free simplicial group $F(S^1)\simeq\Omega S^2$ on the minimal simplicial circle $S^1$ (with a single 1-simplex). $\pi_9(S^2)\cong\pi_8(F(S^1))$ consists of simplices $\sigma\in F(S^1)$ with $d_0(\sigma)=d_1(\sigma)=...=d_8(\sigma)=1$, modulo $d_9(\tau)$ for simplices $\tau$ with $d_0(\tau)=d_1(\tau)=...=d_8(\tau)=1$. So any such $\sigma$ in principle encodes an explicit map from $S^8$ to $\Omega S^2$

Comment: The Hopf fibration implies that $\pi_9(S^2) = \pi_9(S^3)$, so the map is just the composite $S^9 \to S^3 \xrightarrow{\eta} S^2$, where the first map is the generator of $\pi_9(S^3) \cong \mathbf{Z}/3$.

Comment: I think people are mis-understanding the question.  You might need to add some details of what an answer should look like, Alex.

Comment: The question you link to now has two fresh very relevant answers

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I [posted an answer to the previous question](https://mathoverflow.net/a/332740/1345) describing one way to view a generator of $\pi_9 S^3$. From the Hopf fibration
$$S^1\to S^3 \overset{\eta}{\to} S^2$$ and fibration long exact sequence,
we know that $$\pi_9 S^1 = 0 \to \pi_9 S^3 \overset{\eta}{\to} \pi_9 S^2\to \pi_8 S^1=0 $$
is exact, so $\pi_9 S^3 \cong \pi_9 S^2$ via the Hopf map $\eta$ (comment made by @skd above).

I'm not sure if these answers are only understandable by topologists, but all the information is available in Hatcher's book [Algebraic Topology](https://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/ATpage.html) (however, some of the information is not proved there, e.g. Bott periodicity).

Comment: Thank you. What  I want is to  have a picture of  the geometry. (Even if only a bit. Then, at least, I would not have to completely  trust a topologist that  all of this works.)   To do this  your  way I would need  to make sense  of (1) the map $S^8\to S^5$ in $\pi_8 S^5$ and  of (2) the geometry of $\pi_8 S^5\to \pi_9S^3$. Both things look rather obscure to me (even if I more or less understand the argument on the formal level).

Comment: @AlexGavrilov The element $nu$ is very explicit, and hence so is its 3-fold suspension (so the generator of $\pi_8(S^5)$). The other map is harder to describe, but in principle could be computed with a connection, which is essentially canonical from the homogeneity of the situation. I’ll try to add some details tomorrow.

Comment: @AlexGavrilov: a new answer to the other question gives a  fairly explicit realization of the generator for $\pi_9 S^3$. https://mathoverflow.net/a/332750/1345

Comment: I think this description is good enough for me. (And now I do not mind moderators closing my question as a duplicate.)

Answer (score 12):

Since my old answer is referenced here [What is the generator of $\pi_9(S^3)$?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/76899/what-is-the-generator-of-pi-9s3), I spent a little time trying to figure out what it says about this.  "Toda's sequence" is a $p$-local fiber sequence ($p$ any prime) of the form 
$$ S^{2n-1} \to \Omega \widehat{S}^{2n} \to \Omega S^{2pn-1},
$$
where $\widehat{S}^{2n}$ is a certain space I don't need to care about yet; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EHP_spectral_sequence.   This backs up one step to a $p$-local fiber sequence 
$$
\Omega^2 S^{2pn-1} \xrightarrow{f} S^{2n-1} \to \Omega \widehat{S}^{2n}.
$$
The bottom non-trivial homotopy group of the fiber is $\mathbb{Z}$, and so we get a map
$$
\mathbb{Z}=\pi_{2pn-1}S^{2pn-1}=\pi_{2pn-3} \Omega^2 S^{2pn-1} \xrightarrow{f_*} \pi_{2pn-3}S^{2n-1}.
$$
When $p=3$ and $n=2$ this gives $\mathbb{Z}=\pi_{9}\Omega^2S^{11}\to \pi_9S^3$, which by the argument I gave in my other answer surjects with image $\mathbb{Z}/3$.  So we want to compute the image of $f_*$ in this dimension, i.e., the effect on $f$ on the bottom cell of $\Omega^2 S^{2pn-1}$.

Now, when $p=2$, "Toda's sequence" is the James's EHP sequence (with $\widehat{S}^{2n}=S^{2n}$).  In this case $f_*$ is $\mathbb{Z}\to \pi_{4n-3}S^{2n-1}$.  We know what the image of the generator is in this case: it is the "Whitehead square" $[\iota_{2n-1}, \iota_{2n-1}]$, which can be described geometrically as the attaching map of the $4n+2$-cell of $S^{2n-1}\times S^{2n-1}$.

I then tried to figure out what Toda's sequence actually is, in hopes of finding a geometric description of the map, and I failed.  Everyone seems to refer to Toda's *Composition Methods* book for this sequence, but the statement given on Wikipedia is not actually there.  However, the idea of the sequence (together with the other Toda sequence described on wikipedia) seems to be essentially 13.1 in Toda's book.  In turn, 13.1 is not proved in Toda's book, but rather in the paper

> Toda, Hirosi: [On the double suspension $E^2$](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ojm/1353054784), J. Inst. Polytech. Osaka City Univ. Ser. A. 7 (1956), 103–145.

The fiber sequence I am interested in is essentially Theorem 7.6 of Toda's paper.

Comment: Thanks to the person who provide the reference.  (Our library doesn't have that journal, and therefore didn't tell me it is freely available.)